# how to save float and other types of values as chars in java

Tags: java

i want to save all of the variables into a char based file (txt.. etc)

since in java floats are 4 bytes and chars are 2 bytes

are there any ways to save a float into 2 chars and safely retrieve the float value from the two chars?

for example if the bits of the float is

10101010 11111010 10100011 10101010

then save these float as chars with the bits intact 
then the two chars will be

10101010 11111010 and 10100011 10101010

it doesn't matter how it will look when i open the file with a text editor or anything

Comment: read about binary and text file operations, they are differ and have pros and cons

Comment: If your variables are a part of something, I'd suggest to combine them into a class and use java (xml, json, etc.) serialization so they are read and written as a whole maintaining your data integrity.

Answer (score 1):

When java was designed as improvement upon C++, the intention was to have **text** in java as Unicode, so all scripts might be combined.

- `String, char, Reader, Writer` - for Unicode text
- `byte[], InputStream, OutputStream` - for binary data

Hence `char` is two bytes (using the Unicode format UTF-16).

Not every byte sequence can be written as text due to special escaping in UTF-16, UTF-8 and such.

Thus you should think of storing all as pure binary data, a String as UTF-8 byte sequence:

```
String s = ...
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

For that you must know exactly what your write, and how to read it back. You can use a `DataOutputStream`. It has convenient methods like `writeUTF8`, `writeInt`.